# Is there anyway to get the external ports of the kubernetes cluster

Tags: kubernetes, kubectl

I have exposed a service on an external port on all nodes in a kubernetes
cluster from:

`kubectl create -f nginx-service.yaml`

You have exposed your service on an external port on all nodes in your
cluster.  If you want to expose this service to the external internet, you may
need to set up firewall rules for the service port(s) (tcp:30002) to serve traffic.

See http://releases.k8s.io/release-1.2/docs/user-guide/services-firewalls.md for more details.
service "nginx-service" created.`

Is there anyway to get the external ports of the kubernetes cluster?

Comment: Are you using google cloud or aws or local docker as your kubernetes provider ?     ... kubernetes should be agnostic yet on aws its sketchy

Answer (score 78):

`kubectl get svc --all-namespaces -o go-template='{{range .items}}{{range.spec.ports}}{{if .nodePort}}{{.nodePort}}{{"\n"}}{{end}}{{end}}{{end}}'`

This gets all services in all namespaces, and does basically: "for each service, for each port, if nodePort is defined, print nodePort".

Comment: Can you add some explanation with your answer? It will help OP to understand what you are posting.

Comment: `kubectl get svc --all-namespaces -o go-template='{{range .items}}{{range.spec.ports}}{{if .nodePort}}{{.nodePort}}{{.}}{{"\n"}}{{end}}{{end}}{{end}}' ` this will give more information about each NodePort listed.

Comment: What command does the same as this one but for a specific namespace (without the range)?

Comment: kubectl get svc -n <namespace> -o go-template='{{range .items}}{{range.spec.ports}}{{if .nodePort}}{{.nodePort}}{{"\n"}}{{end}}{{end}}{{end}}'

Comment: ```
kubectl get svc --all-namespaces -o go-template='{{range .items}}{{range.spec.ports}}{{if .nodePort}}{{.nodePort}}{{"\t"}}{{.name}}{{"\n"}}{{end}}{{end}}{{end}}' | sort
``` in case you  also want to identify services associated to each nodePort (in nodePorts ascend order)

Answer (score 30):

I hope this answer is short and simple:

```
kubectl describe service --all-namespaces | grep -i nodeport
```

But, using go template is the ideal option and can be used to extract more details.

Answer (score 17):

```
kubectl get svc --all-namespaces -o go-template='{{range .items}}{{ $save := . }}{{range.spec.ports}}{{if .nodePort}}{{$save.metadata.namespace}}{{"/"}}{{$save.metadata.name}}{{" - "}}{{.name}}{{": "}}{{.nodePort}}{{"\n"}}{{end}}{{end}}{{end}}'
```

This gets not just the used nodeports but the name of the nodeport, the service name and namespace of the service in this format:

```
<namespace>/<service name> - <nodeport name>: <nodeport>
```

Answer (score 13):

If you [view your service](http://kubernetes.io/docs/user-guide/services/operations/#view-a-service) using `kubectl describe service NAME` it should show you what port was assigned (in the NodePort field).

Comment: Yes, I know that. Is there a way to get all of the external ports in one command or others?

Comment: Do you mean the node ports for all of the services in your cluster?

Comment: Yes. Like the command :kubectl get endpoints.
root@jya-SBCR:/home/jya/work# kubectl get endpoints
NAME                    ENDPOINTS                             AGE
ebaserdb-ommp-service   172.16.43.6:3306                      10d
ebaserdb-service        172.16.43.8:3306                      11d
ivlm2-service           172.16.43.4:8080                      11d
kubernetes              10.46.178.197:6443                    26d


Can I get the node ports for all  of the services in one cluster?

Comment: The only way to do it (that I know of) is to write a short script that iterates over the services from `kubectl get services` and runs each one through `kubectl describe service`.

Answer (score 12):

To get extended information about service ports:

```
kubectl describe service -A
```

To get only service endpoints:

```
kubectl get endpoints -A
```

To limit the output by node IP, you can grep by a network mask or use a more sophisticated script.

Comment: `error: a resource cannot be retrieved by name across all namespaces`

Answer (score 10):

...and you can perform the same solution alternatively with a [JsonPath](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/kubectl/jsonpath/)...

- get the external Port (the "nodePort") of **`myservice`** corresponding to the internal port **`1234`**

  ```
   kubectl get svc myservice -o=jsonpath='{.spec.ports[?(@.port==1234)].nodePort}'
  ```
- get a list of all IPs of the Nodes underlying your cluster, in one line

  ```
   kubectl get node -o=jsonpath='{.items[*].status.addresses[?(@.type=="InternalIP")].address}'
  ```

Obviously this information can easily be combined into a convenient bash script to suit any specific needs...

```
#!/bin/bash
#
# discoverService - extract the externally visible Node-IP and port for a specific Service in Kubernetes
#
KUBECTL=kubectl
#
if [[ $# < 2 || "$1" == "-h" ]]
    then
    echo discoverService SERVICENAME INTERNALPORT
    exit -1
fi
SERVICENAME=$1
INTERNALPORT=$2

EXTPORT=`${KUBECTL} get svc $SERVICENAME -o=jsonpath="{.spec.ports[?(@.port==${INTERNALPORT})].nodePort}"`

EXTIP=`${KUBECTL} get node -o=jsonpath='{.items[0].status.addresses[?(@.type=="InternalIP")].address}'`


if [[ -z $EXTPORT ]]
    then
    echo -e "ERROR: service=$SERVICENAME internal-port=$INTERNALPORT not found.\n"
    exit -2
elif [[ -z $EXTIP ]]
    then
    echo -e "ERROR: could not retrieve underlying node IPs.\n"
    exit -2
fi
# Success...
echo $EXTIP:$EXTPORT
```

Comment: The `nodePort` example has a lil typo - it should read instead: `kubectl get svc myservice -o=jsonpath='{.items[*].spec.ports[?(@.port==1234)].nodePort}`

Answer (score 0):

Missing part for me was actual IP address of minikube

```
---->$:kubectl describe service --all-namespaces | grep -i nodeport
Name:                     my-nodeport-service
Type:                     NodePort
NodePort:                 <unset>  30007/TCP
---->$:curl $(minikube ip):30007
```

Answer (score 0):

For the ones who want to get the hostIP as well, here is a command who:

- Use a specific NAMESPACE (default to the current-context one)
- Get the HostIP
- Get the NodePort

```sh
# if want to explicit choose a NAMESPACE uncomment the line bellow and change the value
# NAMESPACE=default && \
if [[ -z $NAMESPACE ]]; then NAMESPACE="$(kubectl config view --minify -o jsonpath='{..namespace}')"; fi && \
kubectl get pod -o=custom-columns=POD_NAME:.metadata.name,IP:.status.hostIP --namespace=${NAMESPACE} && \
kubectl get svc -o=custom-columns=SVC_NAME:.metadata.name,PORT:.spec.ports[0].nodePort --namespace=${NAMESPACE}
```