# Free nodeports in kubernetes Cluster

Tags: kubernetes

How can I find all nodeports are free in a kubernetes cluster that can be used by any service?

Currently I'm using `netstat -pant | grep <12345>`

Is there any better command?

Comment: why do you need this info?

Comment: By default, Kubernetes set NodePort range as 30000 - 32767.  refer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37648553/is-there-anyway-to-get-the-external-ports-of-the-kubernetes-cluster this will fulfil your requirement.

`kubectl get svc --all-namespaces -o go-template='{{range .items}}{{range.spec.ports}}{{if .nodePort}}{{.nodePort}}{{"\n"}}{{end}}{{end}}{{end}}'`

Comment: If I absolutely needed a NodePort service, I'd let Kubernetes pick the port for me.  Usually a LoadBalancer service or an HTTP ingress setup will be much easier to work with.

Answer (score 0):

That's the way how nodeport works. It is same as you can't run two web services on same port of 80 on same server.

You have to adjust the port in your real environment.

Otherwise, let kubernetes to manage